# The union of cyclic subspace is also a cyclic space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory

Given a separable Hilbert space $H$, $U$ is a unitary operator. A cyclic subspace, denoted as $Z(x)$ for some $x\in H$, is defined as the closure of linear span of $U^nx$, where $n\in \Bbb Z$ is any integer number.

> Now we have a sequence of cyclic subspaces, namely, $Z(x_1)\subset Z(x_2)\subset \cdots$. Then the closure of its union, $\overline{\bigcup_iZ(x_i)}$, is also a cyclic subspace.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what this $x$ could be. We can assume that $||x_j||=1$, maybe taking $x\in\bigcap_n C_n$, where $C_n$ is the closed convex hull of $\{x_k,k\geq n\}$, will  work.

Answer (score 4):

Adding some details to @DavideGiraudo's comment: in the context of Hilbert spaces, one might not think of using (an easy case of) the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, namely, that closed unit balls are *compact* in the weak dual topology. Thus, the closure of the convex hull of $C_n=\{x_k:k\ge n\}$ is compact in the weak dual topology, and their intersection is *non-empty*.

Given the *existence* of a (non-zero) vector in that intersection, it is not hard to prove it's cyclic.